# Swift - Shared Core Data in Framework - auto-generated classes aren't public?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios8, watchkit

I'm playing around with sharing a Core Data model in an App Group for a WatchKit app in Swift, loosely following/mimicing [this guy's work](https://github.com/aalittle/CoreDataWatchKit). I've created a custom framework (called `CoreDataKit`) and put the .xcdatamodeld file to be a member only of the framework target; I've created a `CoreDataStack` object which creates and manages the core data stack, which is also a member only of the framework target. Finally, I've created a new entity in the data model, and then used Xcode to auto generate the Swift file for that entity, which gives a class structure that looks like:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class FlightStatus: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var altitude: NSNumber
}
```

When I import `CoreDataKit` into my view controller in the iOS app to start doing Core Data stuff, I'm able to access the `CoreDataStack`, but not the `FlightStatus` class - I get a `Use of undeclared type 'FlightStatus'` error.

When I go into the `FlightStatus.swift` file and make it a *public* class, however, the error goes away. But this makes me a little uncomfortable - I've been trained never to touch the auto-generated Core Data classes, because they may need to be regenerated at any time, and therefore I tend to add helper methods and the like in categories on the auto-generated Core Data classes.

Similarly, I can't access the `altitude` variable unless I make it public.

Am I going wrong somewhere? Is there a way I can ensure that my auto-generated Core Data entity classes can be visible when the framework is imported without having to manually add the `public` keyword to them?

Comment: Just a guess, because this has helped in other situations: manually add `@objc(FilghtStatus)` just above the `class` keyword. This is a "bug" in swift which occasionally leads to managed object subclasses not found.

Comment: Alas, didn't help. (It's a pure Swift project anyway.) Also, that would still require me to manually touch the class.

Comment: "I've been trained never to touch the auto-generated Core Data classes, because they may need to be regenerated at any time, and therefore I tend to add helper methods and the like in categories on the auto-generated Core Data classes." I mentioned the same thing to a Core Data engineer at WWDC last year and he told me they only auto generate their classes the first time around. 

After that you can change it manually. If you can't figure it out, I would say don't sweat it about not wanting to touch the autogenerated Swift classes. As Mundi said, it could be a problem with Swift.

Comment: Oh, I know you *can* change them manually. But I prefer not to do that, because if you later want to change the data model, add some fields or relationships for example, and then you want to quickly regenerate the class, it would overwrite anything you stuck into that class.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add @objc(CoreDataClassName) in your class declaration. Modifying your original code slightly:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(FlightStatus) class FlightStatus: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var altitude: NSNumber
}
```

EDIT: I just saw that you mentioned in the comments of your original post that doing this didn't help. Did you follow the above format exactly? Also, regarding your intuition that you shouldn't mess with the CD auto generated files -- Apple is clearly still working out some of the kinks with Swift's Core Data integration, so unfortunately a bit of tinkering is often required. (Another example: Core Data doesn't autogenerate any support for optionals at the moment.)

Comment: Yep, I followed the above exactly. I suppose I'll wait on this, it's sounding more and more like a Swift Core Data problem. :)